# IPython display can be updated only once

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to update the same `display` multiple times.
But it seems that it can be updated only once.

```
from IPython.display import display
from time import sleep

dis = display('1', display_id=True)
sleep(1)
dis.update('2')
sleep(1)
dis.update('3')
```

With the above code, the second `update()` has no effect.
The number remains `2`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from IPython.display import display
from time import sleep

for i in range(1, 4):
    dis = display(str(i), display_id=True)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: I want to display only one number by using `update()`.
Your code displays 3 numbers.